# php - One Hour Earlier Than Given Datetime

Tags: php, datetime

I'm having a problem here..

Supposed I have this kind of datetime.

```
$date = strtotime($date);
```

I need this to be converted into the Unix-timestamp format but one hour earlier..I tried

```
$date = strtotime($date-86400)
```

, but seemed to me it is wrong. It returned 0 when I sneaked into the table.

What is the appropriate way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: There are 3600 seconds in one hour and 86400 seconds in one day. You have to subtract 3600 seconds. `strtotime($date) - 3600;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

strtotime will give you the unix timestamp of your date. From this timestamp, you then subtract your hour:

```
$date = strtotime($date) - 3600; // 3600 = 60 * 60
```

If you call `strtotime($date - 3600)`, it's like obtaining the time for -3600 (e.g. `strtotime(-3600)`) which makes no sense because strtotime expects a string as first argument.

Comment: There are 3600 seconds in one hour and 86400 seconds in one day.

Comment: Ah yes...I was totally in a mess...I shouldn't count 60*60*24...that gives me seconds in a day... stupid me :(

Answer (score 7):

You could do:

```
$testDateStr = strtotime($date);
$finalDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-1 hour", $testDateStr));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: While this answer is pretty self-explanatory to those who are familiar with `date()` and `strtotime()`, It would improve your answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 3):

86400 seconds is one DAY, not one hour.

The output of strtotime() is a unix timestamp.  3600 seconds earlier is that timestamp minus one hour.  So:

```
$date = strtotime($somestring);

$hourago = $date - 3600;
```

Or, depending on the original format of $somestring:

```
$hourago = strtotime($somestring . " - 1 hour");
```

And don't forget about [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set)

Answer (score 3):

Nobody offered a `DateTime` object solution yet, so I will.
It is the most modern method for handling datetime and doesn't require any calculation of minutes & seconds.

I always like to drop in some sort of timezone declaration to make things definitive.  Daylight Saving Time is normally a concern with datetime manipulations, but probably okay in this case.  Feel free to modify the timezone for your case.

PHP manual links:

- [DateTime Object](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)
- [DateTime modify()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php)
- [DateTime getTimestamp()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php)
- [DateTime format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)
- [Timezone List](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Code (including formatted time for comparison) [Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4ac224ac492e84f1e97dba0f163edfddb3af3741):

```
$now=new DateTime('NOW UTC');

$now_stamp=$now->getTimestamp();
$formatted_now=$now->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo "$now_stamp ($formatted_now)\n";

$hour_ago=$now->modify('-1 hour');
$hour_ago_stamp=$hour_ago->getTimestamp();
$formatted_hour_ago=$hour_ago->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo "$hour_ago_stamp ($formatted_hour_ago)";
```

Output:

```
1492687193 (2017-04-20 11:19:53)
1492683593 (2017-04-20 10:19:53)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
$query= "insert into yourTable(otherValues, date) 
values (otherFields, DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 hour))
```

Use DATE_ADD to insert a date value which is 1 hour less than current time.

Comment: Downvoted because OP doesn't ask for a `mysql` solution nor an `INSERT`.  All answers should also include some sort of explanation so that readers can fully understand/benefit from the answer/approach.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's better way:

```
// It's better to set your time location, for example, in Iran.
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tehran");
$datetime = new DateTime(date());

// Subtract one hour
$interval = new DateInterval("PT1H");
$datetime->sub($interval);

// Format and echo the updated datetime
echo $datetime->format("H:i:s");
```