# Create a php variable storing the time one hour before the present IST time

Tags: php

I have converted the current `UTC` time to `IST`, and now I need to convert this time to one hour before,and store it in a variable.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$DateTime=date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$DateTime=date('H:i:s',$DateTime - 3600);//This does not seem to work 
echo $DateTime;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/790949)

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$DateTime=date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$DateTime=date('H:i:s',  strtotime($DateTime) - 3600);
echo $DateTime;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the operation you want to perform you need to use timestamp. You can not add or subtract a number from date string.

Use something like this

```
$timeBeforeAnHour = date('H:i:s',time() - 3600);
```

This would help.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will give you the unix timestamp of your date. From that timestamp, you then subtract your one hour

[Referred from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9459946/3282633)

You should do `date('H:i:s',strtotime($DateTime)-3600);`

So, It should be

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$DateTime=date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$DateTime=date('H:i:s',strtotime($DateTime) - 3600);
echo $DateTime;
?>
```

Here's the [eval link](https://eval.in/755074)

Comment: The code only uses the date function only to get current time at first. So don't you think it is unnecessary to create a date and convert it to timestamp instead you can directly get the current timestamp in php.